# How to sort data from DropDownList component?

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

I'm developing a simple Web App which has a simple data from some employees, such as ID, NAME and so on. Thus, I'm using a XML file as my database. Yet, **my XML file is sorted by the Employees' ID**.

However, I'm using a  to select the Employee's Name and show some informations about him/her, but when I created the bindable data through my spark component (I just "drag-and-drop" my  XML file into the component), I'd like to show those names sorted by Name and this is my problem.

It's suppose to be a simple code, but I'm in trouble with it... lol!

```
<s:DropDownList id="ddNome"
                labelField="NomeFuncionario" <!-- Employees' Name -->
                textAlign="justify"
                width="240" height="25"
                top="30" horizontalCenter="0"
                initialize="sortName(event)" <!-- Trying to create it now... -->
                creationComplete="cbNome_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                change="cbNome_changeHandler(event)">

    <s:AsyncListView list="{getDataResult2.lastResult}"/>

</s:DropDownList>
```

I'd be really grateful for any help with this code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
    <mx:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl"
            source="{getDataResult2.lastResult}">
        <mx:sort>
            <mx:Sort>
                <mx:fields>
                    <mx:SortField id="sortField"
                            name="@NomeFuncionario"
                            caseInsensitive="true" />
                </mx:fields>
            </mx:Sort>
        </mx:sort>
    </mx:XMLListCollection>

    ...
    <s:AsyncListView list="{xmlListColl}"/>
    ...
```

Comment: I've got and error with the <mx:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl" source="{getDataResult2.lastResult}"> and the <s:AsyncListView list="{xmlListColl}"/> tag blocks.

The Flash Builder tells me that "Multiple initializer values for default property, 'dataProvider', of type 'mx.collections.IList'.